# Creating Drag Drop div layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to create a iGoogle kind of layout in which you can drag and drop different widgets in different places. I have to use javascript or jquery only. I wanted to know how to go about it. Basically how to start and implement this kind of structure.

P.S.: I cant use any specific framework which does this job. I have to create it myself.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me :) Any business would choose an add-in.

Comment: i could swap the div elements until now with each other but do not have the animation effect to it. Also i do not want them to be swapped, rather moved when i place one in place of another. still working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use draggable and droppable jquery plugins. See example here

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert

**update**

You have to write your own dragable function. The trick is you listen to onmousedown event and then redraw the element at current x, y postion.

Look at this [example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/)

**Note** : if you want to learn, then do not copy paste the example. Try to understand and then implement on your own !

Comment: Cant use jquery UI. Can only use javascript or plain Jquery. Any help with that would be great

Comment: That's a start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery UI's Sortable interaction functionality, should give you a good starting point.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: Cant use jquery UI. Can only use javascript or plain Jquery.